# Backward Compatibility Option not available in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello Guys I am learning android, I am completely new, I brought a book
"HEAD FIRST ANDROID 2017 EDITION".
[android head first tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UopN2.png)
i am following the procedure, i downloaded the android studio as they are instructed in the chapter, but one glitch I suffering there is a check box as seen there written Backward compatibility she instructed me to uncheck it.
[android screenshot without app compat option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/craGP.png)
but the problem is in the 3.3 android studio there is no option of backward compatibility how to do that ?

**by the way one more doubt is that is it necessary to listen what she is guiding( to un check app compat)
can i continue without listening her, continue with  app compat will i get any problem in future tutorial pages.**

Comment: "how to do that ?" -- the new-project wizard no longer supports that. You would have to set up the activities by hand. You might want to see what version of Android Studio is being used by that book, then use that version of Android Studio, until you get more comfortable with Android app development.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably late but it might be helpful to someone.
I tried this with Android Studio 3.3 and its appears it automatically adds the support library.
Go to File > Project Structure. Then click on the app module and
choose Dependencies you will likely see the **com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0**

[project structure window android 3.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBUGU.png)